# cant find any files in file manager in android monitor

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

When I try to browse emulator files with Eclipse's DDMS, I see none of those files. How to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to reset the adb

Comment: click on some app... i.e com.etc .

Comment: no matter how many times i reset no files are shown.
i tried to click on some app but no use.

Comment: if you use API 24 or 25, there is a bug : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229628.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is occurs because the device is an Emulator.

See, My Lenovo phone's files can be browsed easily.

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lFvo.png)

Comment: I too can see the files when i connect my phone, but I don't see any files in emulator.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Why you're using emulator while you have a Android Device? Emulators are slower than Devices.